# How to apply an id attribute in React if I use Bootstrap elements

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I struggled with my React app,I use model from Bootstrap 4 and when I want to change an id="myModal" to the id id I need `` id=`id${todo.id}` `` the model does not open, if I don't change the id in input field I have always the same todo does not matter which I open to edit. How I could change the id and keep model working?
Here is my code just in case:

```
export default function EditTodo({ todo }) {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(todo);
  console.log("Edit Todo!!!!", todo);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {/* <!-- Button to Open the Modal --> */}
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal" **/// Can't change that data-target is not working than ///**
      >
        Edit
      </button>

      {/* <!-- The Modal --> */}
      <div className="modal" id="myModal"> ***/// Can't change that id the model is not working than ///***
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            {/* <!-- Modal Header --> */}
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h4 className="modal-title">Edite A Todo</h4>
              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
            </div>

            {/* <!-- Modal body --> */}
            <div class="modal-body">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={todo.description}
                onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>

            {/* <!-- Modal footer --> */}
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Edit
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-danger"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use
`` id={`id${todo.id}`} `` & `` data-target={`id${todo.id}`} `` (Mind the brackets)

Comment: if i use that the model is not opening at all

Comment: Are you receiving any console errors after clicking the open button? if so, mind to share those?

Comment: no errors at all, the page doesn't react when I press the button, Just warning ```did you mean className? ``` That's it.